# Origami's dog card

Tags: untagged

The dog card says to pick 1 card from the deck and one card for each sheep visible. What sheep is it referring too? The sheep in my collection or the sheep in the collections of other players as well?

Comment: What game are you talking about?

Comment: @JoeW Based on the tittle, I'd guess this: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/234469/origami

Comment: Tag edited. Note that the "playing-cards" tag description notes that it  "*is not* a meta tag for adding to any card game question!"

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson isn't a tag for card games ?

Comment: @andreasperelli Right. See the description of the tag on the tag page: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playing-cards

Answer (score 1):

All visible means all the ones you can see.

The designer, Christian Giove, confirms on [this BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/32072244#32072244):

> you count sheeps on top of ALL COLLECTIONS (your own and those of
>   other player) plus those in the DRAW LINE and also the card on the top
>   of the DISCARD PILE.

Comment: I didn't find anything in the rules about the discard deck...